# Delay measurement and synchronisation between raspberry pi

Tags: c, linux, matlab

I am doing a project with 2 raspberry pi which work as servers and a laptop which is the client.
I have attached to each raspberry and usb microphone and using the Portaudio Library im capturing audio streaming
and send it back to the laptop through a tcp/ip connection.

The scope of this project is to locate sound sources and it works like this. I run a .c file on each raspberry which are
connected on the same LAN as with the PC laptop. When this program is running on both raspberryies i have a message 
"Waiting connection for a client". The next thing to do is just to run the matlab file which will start the both raspberries
and record. I have managed to synchronize the raspberries to start in the same time through a simple condition like

```
do 
{
    sleep(0.01);
    j = read(newsockfd, &start,1 );
} while (j==0);
```

so right before both raspberries have to start recording i pause them in order to finish the initialization commands and so on
and then i just send a character "start = 'k'" through my matlab program 
t1,t2 are tcp connections

```
start = 'k';
fwrite (t1, k);
fwrite (t2, k);
```

from this point both raspberries open the PortAudio stream and call recordCallBack function. 
When I run the application and clap, i still get a delay of 0.2s between them which causes
an error of 60 meters. I have also checked the execution time of the fwrite function but that might
save me about 0.05 seconds which will still lead to results far from reality.
This project is based on TDOA measurement and it is desired to have a delay under 0.01 seconds to get accuracy <1m.

I have heard that linux has some very accurate timers, and i was thinking that maybe i could use that to
clock the time inside the functions in the .c file. Anyway if you have any ideas of how i can measure the delay from 
the point i send the character 'k' from matlab until the point where the audio stream is opened in microphone, or any 
way how i could synchronize the 2 linux servers please help.

ps: both are raspberry 2 pi and connected through UTP cables so the processing and transmission rates should be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to synchronise clocks. It could be in a *system level* or in *application level*.

System level tend to be easier because there are already tools to do the job. I don't recommend you doing PTP at this stage, as mentioned by Emilien, [since it is quite complicated to make it work](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Configuring_PTP_Using_ptp4l.html). Instead I would recommend you to use normal [setup via the same NTP network on all machines](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-Date_and_Time_Configuration-Command_Line_Configuration-Network_Time_Protocol.html).

Example of NTP setup:

1. Query the server with `# ntpdate -q 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org`
2. If it is running, setup your local clock with `# ntpdate 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org 1.rhel.pool.ntp.org`

> OBS: **#** means root user (which most likely means that you will need to run the command with `sudo`), whilst **$** means normal user.

Check all machines times with `$ date +%k:%M:%S.%N` which will return the clock down to a nanosecond resolution.

> If that doesn't acheive the desired result then try the PTP aproach, or just synchronise all your devices when they connect to the master, where your master can normalise each independant clock. I will not go into details here.

Then you can send your audio data via TCP/IP (or perhaps UDP/IP to lower latency) like you mentioned before, but always send the timestamp of your slave machine associated to a audio frame using [clock_gettime()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) function with `CLOCK_REALTIME` as the `clk_id` argument.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an interesting project but I think you underestimate the problem a little bit. The first issue is that you need to [synchonize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_synchronization) the two sensors. Given the speed of sound and if you want an accuracy of about 1m you need to synchronize them with about 1ms accuracy. You could try with the Network Time Protocol but I'm not sure you can reach this accuracy even with a master on the local network. Better synchronization can be achieved with [PTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) (over ethernet) or GPS if you can receive a GPS signal.

Then if you manage to achieve this, a first step could be to record a few hand claps on both raspberry pi, save the timestamp when you start recording on both and see if you actually obtain something significant. Maybe you will also need to use a microcontroller and a real-time operating system instead!